# Automated crash report service for hybrid (cordova) apps

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, crash-reports, crashlytics

Is there an automated crash reporting solution similar to crashlytics for mobile hybrid apps?
Those apps are wrapping a webview and can contain bindings to native implementations such as camera, gps, etc.

I wonder if there is any solution that can integrate in the mobile app that will capture both javascript and web errors as well as native errors.

Comment: Hey did you find any good crash report service?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like now there are couple of solutions for this using Fabric / Crashlytics
Both seems to be external plugins for cordova

1. https://github.com/sarriaroman/FabricPlugin
2. https://github.com/verheyefrancesco/cordova-plugin-crashlytics